# evenment onclick javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my code

```
<tr>
    <td id="<?php echo; $id ?>" onclick="addrow(?php echo $id; ?>)">...</td>
</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
```

css:

```
.ndisplay {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function addrow($id) {
    var id = document.getElementById($id);

    if (id.hasClass("ndisplay")) {
        id.removeClass("ndisplay");
    } else {
        id.addClass("ndisplay");
    }
}
```

That's work but just for the first `tr` ...
The problem it's `$id` is the same value for each `tr` but i'm forced to use the same id for each `<tr>`

I have testing with a div between the `tr` but it doesn't work.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Why are you "forced to use the same `id`"? That's not even valid HTML. `id` attribute should be unique.

Comment: Regardless of the (bizarre) necessity of using repeated `id` values, they're still invalid, and scripting around them is *not* going to work. `getElementById()` will *always* return the first one, and only the first.

Comment: Perhaps you can give them all the same class, instead of the same id. That is common practice in HTML.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the code? Adding a row to a table?

Comment: it is also invalid having `<div>` as child of a `<tr>` and using `id` as a variable to represent a DOM element is going to lead to lots of confusion...bad habit

Answer (score 1):

The person who forced to use same ID for all tr elements, say him/her to purchase a beginners book for html and js,  in other words it is not valid in HTML specification, you will have to use same classes rather then same id's , :)

Answer (score 0):

At least, with `$id1`, `$id2`, `$id3`, `$id4` being different :

```
<tr>
    <td id="<?php echo; $id1 ?>" onclick="addrow(?php echo $id1; ?>)">...</td>
</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $id2; ?>" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $id3; ?>" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="<?php echo $id4; ?>" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this it should work (Open to corrections)

```
<tr id="1" onClick="addrow()" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="2" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="3" class="ndisplay">...</tr>
<tr id="4" class="ndisplay">...</tr>

<style type="text/css">
    .ndisplay {
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function addrow(e) {
        var div = e.target;
        if(div.hasClass("ndisplay")) {
            div.removeClass("ndisplay");
        }
        else {
            div.addClass("ndisplay");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: never give the same id to multiple elements